# Getting python to stop printing lines from a file at a certain time using Re

Tags: python, python-re

Basically what I am trying to do is to get it to print the lines of a file that have a timestamp in a specific range that is input from the user.

```
import sys, re

f = open('log.txt', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
h = open('errorsfound.txt', "w")
print("What time do you want to begin searching the logs?")
starttimestamp = input()
starttimestamp = str(starttimestamp)
print("What time do you want to stop searching the logs?")
endtimestamp = input()
endtimestamp = str(endtimestamp)
use = False
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:

  if re.search(starttimestamp, line): use = True
  if re.search(endtimestamp, line): use = False
  if use:
      if "error" in line:
          h.write (line)
  if use:
      if "Failed" in line:
          h.write (line)
  if use:
      if "ERROR" in line:
          h.write (line)
  if use:
      if "WARN" in line:
          h.write (line)
  if use:
      if "Requeue:" in line:
          h.write (line)


f.close()
h.close()
```

I have it to where it prints starting from a certain time, but I'm having trouble getting it to stop printing after a certain time.  The timestamps are in format 04:00:48.  So when it prompts I input say 04:00:48 as the start time and 04:15:48 as the end time.  I am a fairly new coder so I apologize if I have left anything out.  Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 0):

As a new coder you are missing some format but good job anyways!

For time you should get used to use modules like datetime, using str() on input is redundant since it saves the result of the input as str already, and least but not last re is for regular expressions, there are other ways of parsing text ( if my_text in line: then x) but re is a good tool anyways.

```
import sys, re
import datetime

f = open('log.txt', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
h = open('errorsfound.txt', "w")
print("What time do you want to begin searching the logs?")
starttimestamp = str(input()) # redundant use of str()
print("What time do you want to stop searching the logs?")
endtimestamp = str(input())   # redundant use of str()
# use = False # bad name for a variable, use more descripting ones
write_time_flag = False
lines = f.readlines()

"""
    my_solution
"""

try:
    start_time_stamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(input, "%H:%M:%S")
    break
except:
    print("Use Format Hours:Minutes:seoconds (HH:MM:SS)")

try:
    end_time_stamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(input, "%H:%M:%S")
    break
except:
    print("Use Format Hours:Minutes:seoconds (HH:MM:SS)")

for line in lines:

  # I don't know the format of your log file so, read the hours with datetime
  # and check condition

  if readtime > start_time_stamp and readtime < end_time_stamp:
      use = True
  else:
      use = False

  if use:
      if "error" in line:
          h.write (line)
      elif "Failed" in line:
          h.write (line)
      elif "ERROR" in line:
          h.write (line)
      elif "WARN" in line:
          h.write (line)
      elif "Requeue:" in line:
          h.write (line)

f.close()
h.close()
```